# Automating SSL certificate expiry notification in SAP PO key store

Tags: automation, sap-pi

I want to develop an automation for getting alert notification to my email id whenever the SSL certificate is going to expire in SAP PI/PO keystore. SSL certifiates are stored in TrustedCA.
I would be very obliged to take input from experts about how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily if you have been using **SAP PO B2B Add-on** in addition to SAP PI/PO (B2B add-on is included in your SAP PI/PO license). You can enable Certificate Alerts Settings in B2B Integration cockpit.

1. If not already configured, Follow Michal's tip https://blogs.sap.com/2012/03/25/michals-pi-tips-component-based-message-alerting/ and configure the CBMA alert as described
2. Navigate to B2B Integration Cockpit https://host:port/b2bic and go to Trading Partner Management and switch to Administration tab and do the configuration as below.
3. Provide a Queue Name (Alert consumer) which will be used for the alert (If already created for other CBMA alert, You can use the same, else follow step 1 and create an alert consumer e.g. CERTALERT-TO-MAIL etc.).
4. Tick the checkboxes of "Enable Alerts", "Enable Expiry Alerts" and enable the "NWA KeyStore Profile". Also mention the due to expiry date to get the alerts.
   [settings maintained in B2BIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTtFh.png)

This will enable the certificate alert and it will contain the info such as "Key Store View Name" and due to expire certificate name as maintained in the key store.

In order to test this parallelly, you can also restart or start/stop **com.sap.aii.b2b.certalert.app** application in NWA.

Hope this helps!